# Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'BizTalk' provider failed

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-ps1-provider

I'm getting the error:

> "Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the
>   'BizTalk' provider failed.".

I got this working on our BizTalk Dev system several months ago; just installed the Production server today, and getting the error.

Using BizTalk 2016 on Win 2012.

I ran the command:

```
  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
 .\BizTalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions.dll
```

and I'm using PowerShell 4 in 32-bit mode:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\myusername> get-pssnapin -registered


Name        : BizTalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions
PSVersion   : 4.0
Description : Windows PowerShell CmdLets and Provider for Microsoft Biztalk Server

Name        : WDeploySnapin3.0
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : This is a PowerShell snap-in that contains cmdlets for managing Microsoft Web Deployment infrastructure.



PS C:\Users\myusername> Add-PSSnapIn -Name BiztalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions
Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'BizTalk' provider failed.
PS C:\Users\myusername> Add-PSSnapIn -Name BiztalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions
PS C:\Users\myusername> Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

Comment: Have you tried running it as Admin?

Comment: Yes, same error running as Admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Development environment, BizTalk and SQL were on the same sever, but in Production environment, they are on different servers.

Apparently if on different servers, you have to add this line:

```
New-PSDrive -Name BizTalk -Root BizTalk:\ -PsProvider BizTalk -Instance MySqlServer -Database BizTalkMgmtDb
```

Just replace "MySqlServer" with your server name.

Got the idea/solution here: [Installing the BizTalkFactory PowerShell Provider on BizTalk 2013](https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2014/06/installing-biztalkfactory-powershell-provider-biztalk-2013/), where he talks about creating a Profile.ps1 file.  Or possibly I created that Profile.ps1 in Dev, and just forgot about it; checking on that now.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone stumbles over this old post, to stop the error, just set this variable before hand:

```
$InitializeDefaultBTSDrive = $false
```

It also makes it a lot faster.

An alternative to adding the snapin is to just import the module, so your script becomes:

```
$InitializeDefaultBTSDrive = $false
Import-Module "$env:BTSINSTALLPATH\SDK\Utilities\PowerShell\BizTalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions.dll" -WarningAction Ignore
New-PSDrive -Name BizTalk -PSProvider BizTalk -Root BizTalk:\ -Instance mybiztalksqlservername.mydomain -Database BizTalkMgmtDb
```

Comment: What permissions are required for `New-PSDrive -Name BizTalk...`? Currently I'm getting an access denied error, probably because I don't have administration rights. I'm trying to execute a PowerShell script with lower rights for BizTalk configuration and deployment...