# Connect to a remote BizTalk server using Powershell Extensions for BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, powershell-4.0, biztalk-2013

How can I connect to a remote BizTalk Server using `BiztalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions`.

This is how I start to run a script on current server:

```
Add-PSSnapIn -Name BiztalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions  
#NOTE: Must be in 32-bit version of Powershellto use this SnapIn
cd "Biztalk:\Applications"
```

Would it be something like this?  Would it have to be in the same domain?

```
cd "Remote1\\Biztalk:\Applications"
```

Also, if BizTalks SQL server for the BizTalkMGMTDB is not on same server as BizTalk, how do we handle this?  Seems like I did it a prior company, but cannot find the answer today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in one of my old posts: [Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'BizTalk' provider failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089732/attempting-to-perform-the-initializedefaultdrives-operation-on-the-biztalk-pro)

Apparently if SQL and BizTalk are on different servers, you have to add this line:

```
New-PSDrive -Name BizTalk -Root BizTalk:\ -PsProvider BizTalk -Instance MySqlServer -Database BizTalkMgmtDb
```

Just replace "MySqlServer" with your server name.